# Unexplained differences in iteration between gnuplot 4.6 and gnuplot 5.0

Tags: iteration, gnuplot

In trying to answer a gnuplot question that involved the need to iterate over dates, I was told that my solution didn't work with gnuplot 4.6.  In investigating why, I noticed a strange difference in how gnuplot 4.6 and gnuplot 5.0 are handling the same iteration construct.

Consider these two iteration expressions

```
do for [i=396835200:397094400:86400] {print i}
do for [i=396835200:397008000:86400] {print i}
```

In gnuplot 5.0, the first produces

```
396835200
396921600
397008000
397094400
```

and the second produces

```
396835200
396921600
397008000
```

but in gnuplot 4.6, the first produces only the first two numbers and the second produces one extra number (397094400).

Why is this happening?  The gnuplot 5.0 behavior is correct according to the definition of iteration in gnuplot.  Was there a bug that was fixed in gnuplot 5.0?

I had suspected that it may be related to an integer overflow, but I don't think these numbers are quite large enough to trigger that (they all easily fit in a 32 bit signed integer).

I had also suspected that there may have been a change in iteration so that the upper bound was checked using < in version 4.6 and <= in version 5.0, but that still wouldn't explain this (it *almost* would if the 4.6 outputs of those expressions were switched).

Why are these do versions behaving differently here?  Any reference to changes in the release notes, or source code changes would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24284113/2604213

Comment: Thank you @Christoph.  With your link, I am now trying to decide if I should delete this question as it is so similar to that one.  It is the same bug, but I am thinking this question still might be valuable to leave for people that encounter this as a difference between versions like I did.  I'm not sure if they would necessary find that question (I didn't), and it is a similar but different question than that one.  I'd welcome input from anyone on if I should leave this as valuable by itself or if it should be removed due to the similarities.

Comment: I would leave your question and accept the answer. I could only find the other question because I knew it exists.

Comment: This is another related bug: [1441](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1441/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I managed to find an answer myself.  This is apparently a bug that appeared in gnuplot and was fixed in version 5.0.

The actual bug is reported at the gnuplot bug reports as bug number [1429](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1429/) with a description roughly equivalent to mine, as well as a more detailed explanation of the fix in [1358](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1358/).

This was fixed in version 5.0rc1 and version 4.6 patchlevel 6.

I won't repeat the source code here, as I don't know about the license restrictions, but there is a change in the file *parse.c* in the **next_iteration** function, where a patch was added to prevent an overflow caused by multiplying two large numbers together (and apparently a similar patch was needed in at least one other place).